# AccountQuery returns all accounts with the incorrect Type

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm getting a list of accounts from Quickbooks online and all the  AccountTypeEnum types are set to Asset. This is not right. Is there a better way to get this data with the correct account types like Revenue and Expense?

```
        OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = Initializer.InitializeOAuthValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        ServiceContext context = Initializer.InitializeServiceContext(oauthValidator, realmId, string.Empty, string.Empty, dataSourcetype);
        DataServices commonService = new DataServices(context);
        int currentPage = 1;
        int itemListPageSize = 100;
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery qboAccQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountQuery();
        IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account> qboAccounts = commonService.FindAll(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account(), currentPage, itemListPageSize) as IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account>;
```

Answer (score 2):

QBO does not return the Type for accounts, only the SubType.  Please see:

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Account

Type is exposed in the DevKit for QBO Accounts, but it is never set, which is why it is always Asset.

Comment: How do I filter the list by only Income and Expense accounts?

Comment: Filtering by account type is not supported.

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Account#Attributes_Supporting_Filtering_and_Sorting